# du to just look at directories and sort by size

Tags: bash, sorting, summary, du

There are very long threads on this, I've read all that I could find, they don't answer my question.

The following is the best I can find to get a nicely formatted `du` listing inside a folder:

```
du -hsc $(ls -A) | sort -h
```

However, it's not what I want exactly as I want it to filter out / not show files in the top folder. I just want to get a summary of the directories (including `.*` directories) without the clutter of individual files. I think I would need to modify the `ls` but don't know how?

Even better would be to do the above, and additionally show a line of just the combined size of all files that are in the top level of this folder to show alongside all of the subfolder totals if that's possible?

Comment: You could just use `-F` in ls and then filter out the lines that don't end in `/`. eg `du -hsc $(ls -AF) | sort -h | sed '\@/$@!d'`

Comment: The threads that I saw on this were tortuous, most answers couldn't even do the above - it took maybe 20 answers to get to something half-useful - `ls` is not as simple or as usable as it could be, it's a little bit awkward to get tailored output.

Comment: That seems to work nicely (the `total` line seems to be removed, but I don't mind that). This is great, thanks William.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you want to use `ls` here. A simple

```
old_setting=$(shopt -p dotglob)
shopt -s dotglob
du -hsc */
eval $old_setting
```

would be sufficient. The terminating slash is important, as this instructs bash to only create directory names, and you need to set *dotglob* to include dot-directories (except `.` and `..`). In my code I have also carefully saved the old *dotglob* setting and restored it otherwise. You only need to do this if your code is part of a large script where some part of it may rely on the default value for *dotglob*.

Side note: A completely different approach would be to choose zsh instead of bash for your script. In zsh, you don't need to change any option, but just express in the pattern itself that you want to glob the dot-directories:

```
du -hsc */(D)  # This is for zsh only!
```

Comment: I'm glad you posted this, as it illustrates the problem. Quite simply: this approach does not pick up `.*` folders, and considering that in some cases, `.*` folders can hold huge amounts of data, then `du -hsc */` is almost completely useless in trying to get a *comprehensive* understanding of where the space in a folder is located (the lack of usefulness of this output is exactly why I'm asking this question actually - I want a rigorous way to analyse the disk usage in a folder, but `du -hsc */` simply does not achieve that).

Comment: @YorSubs : You can tell bash to expand dotfiles too. I will amend my answer with this information.

Comment: That's great, as you can see, it's a lot more awkward than it first appears when you consider that `.*` folders can contain huge amounts of data (and that normally, `du -hsc */` just doesn't pick that up). This extended answer is really useful, I would never have known either the `shopt` or `zsh` possibilities, very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @YorSubs : If you find it useful, I would appreciate if you could accept the answer.

Comment: I find all of the answers here really interesting and useful. What makes this the "best" answer would you say?

Comment: This is something you have to choose. It should be an answer which you believe is correct, and which you actually intend to use for your problem. This is discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374296/accept-more-than-1-answer) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon).

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I want, as it does not require additional tools like `ls` to achieve things. I've put it into my `.bashrc` as a one-liner function `dusort() { local dotglob=$(shopt -p dotglob); shopt -s dotglob; du -hsc */ | sort -h; eval $dotglob; }` and that will be very useful. Frankly, I think it is absolutely crazy that `du` does not have a switch "also include folders starting dot" as in my home folder, a ".mozilla" folder is 90 MB, a full 25% of my entire home folder, so without this, `du` is (out of the box) a *really really bad* tool for examining disk usage(!) ...

Comment: This is not crazy at all, if you consider that `du` can't even **know** that you have used a wildcard for selecting files. It just sees an explicit list of the filenames, and it is up to the shell to expand your pattern into the file list. I admit that I prefer the approach taken by zsh, and it was actually when I discovered about wildcard flags such as `(D)` or `(N)`, when I decided to switch from bash to zsh. Of couse everyone has its own preferences....

Comment: Hard to defend this architectural decision of bash (or Unix / Linux in general I guess?). i.e. `du` should match all folder objects by default. Having a *blocker* (the `dotglob` option) is almost inconceivably bizarre. `.xxx/` should be matched by `*`, it's really that simple, and this choice leads to things like `du` being effectively broken. i.e. it is a "disk usage" tool that is *prevented* from reporting meaningful disk usage information due to an extremely bad architectural decision. I love Linux, but  it's scary that so few people know how/why `du` doesn't work properly (and by design!).

Comment: Please complain to the original inventors of Unix, long time before bash existed. They decided in their wisdom, that the concept of _invisible file_ would be helpful: They are there, but you usually don't see them. Hence, the globbing expanded only to **visible** files. This is often convenient (think about MacOS, where you otherwise get crazy about the many .DS_store entries), but it comes for the price, that you have to explicitly do something if you don't want this behaviour. I don't like the bash approach and prefer zsh's way instead.

Comment: @YorSubs: BTW, if you want just the total of all files (including hidden ones) below your PWD, and nothing else, you don't need globbing at all. Just do a `du -hsc .`.

Comment: I'm not complaining at all in fact, and complaining to the original inventors of Unix is pointless. I'm pointing out that this is *meaningful-at-the-time-but-nonsensical-now*. The decision of the "invisible file" was bad as it makes many tools (like `du`) broken in their *default* usage (e.g. my `.mozilla` is 25% of my home folder but not reported by `du`!!). I am simply making a *relevant observation of reality*. I get you with things like `.ds_store` entries (which are themselves *another* bad decision), but it's still *anti-useful* that `du` does not usefully report by default(!).

Comment: Thanks on the `du -hsc .`. I was still thinking about that and so I'll add that into to my function to finally make `du` quite a useful directory usage reporting tool (as opposed to the anti-useful tool that it is out-of-the-box). This function will now be a fixture in my bash profile that I'll use a lot I think. 

Comment: Actually, I'm veering towards using `ls -alc` for that part (unless you have a better suggestion). `dusort() { local dotglob=$(shopt -p dotglob); shopt -s dotglob; du -hsc */ | sort -h; eval $dotglob; printf "\n$(ls -alc | grep ^total) (size of files in current directory only)\n"; }`

Comment: With this, you run in the usual problems you get when parsing the output from `ls`. I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

(Mostly) repeated from comments:

You could just use -F in ls and then filter out the lines that don't end in /. eg `du -hsc $(ls -AF) | sort -h | sed '\@/$@!d'`

This will remove the total, and you can get that back easily with:

```
du -hsc $(ls -AF) | sort -h | sed '$p; \@/$@!d'
```

Comment: Do you know how I might get that into an alias? Following (and various other attempts replacing `'` and `"`) didn't work for me: `alias dusort='du -hsc $(ls -AF) | sort -h | sed "$p; \@/$@!d"'`

Comment: I strongly recommend using functions instead of aliases.  `dusort() { du -hsc ...; }` should work without needed to change the quote character.

Comment: Works great, thanks. Could you expand a little on the meaning of the three `sed` elements that I don't understand please: `$p; `, `$@` (don't see why the `$` is there) and `!d`?

Comment: `$p` means print the last line. ($ address matches the last line, p prints).  The `$@` is two separate tokens.  `/$` matches a literal `/` anchored at the end of the line, and `@` is the regex delimiter.  The `!` in `!d` negates the address, so the `d` command is applied to all lines that do not match the regex `/$`.

Comment: This works perfectly in my home folder. On going to `/etc`, I got problems (which makes sense, `du: cannot read directory 'xxx/': Permission denied`, `du: cannot access 'xxx@': No such file or directory`, first relates more to `ls` trying to resolve, so I moved the `sed` inside the `ls` command substitution and `sudo`, and the second more to `du` going through subdirs, so I have to give `du` a `sudo` as well: `sudo du -hsc $(sudo ls -AF | sed '$p; \@/$@!d') | sort -h`. Maybe I'll create 2 functions, `dusort` and `dusortsu` with the `sudo`'s (unless there is a better way).

Answer (score 1):

Without parsing the output of `ls` which is a terrible choice:

```sh
printf %s\\n .[^.]*/ ..[^.]/ ..[^.]*/ */ |
  xargs du -hsc 2>/dev/null |
    sort -k1h
```

If you need to support directories names with newline or special chars:

```sh
printf %s\\0 .[^.]*/ ..[^.]/ ..[^.]*/ */ |
  xargs -0 du -hsc0 2>/dev/null |
    sort -zk1h |
      xargs -0l
```

Comment: Can you say why the output of `ls` is a terrible choice - I was thinking that `ls` was a reasonable way to pick folders, but curious to know why it might not be good? Using `printf` and `xargs` like this is absolutely fascinating to me, lots for me to learn here(!) :). Wherever I try this though, I get errors, e.g. both in my home folder, or in `/etc/` (where I do expect to get permission errors), I still always get the following error (twice) in both: `du: cannot access '..[^.]/': No such file or directory. du: cannot access '..[^.]*/': No such file or directory`. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @YorSubs Here is an extended discussion at unix.stackexchange.com about: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/310674).

Comment: @YorSubs about `..[^.]/': No such file or directory` with Bash, add a `shopt -s nullglob before the printf`. I will adapt/filter out wit grep to remove the patterns from the results.